# Best practices in designing bread crumbs

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm working on a website with large number of pages and trying to add a breadcrumb. These are a few things i found from researching internet. Are these best practices? Is there a better guideline in doing this?

1. Should there be underlines for the breadcrumbs to make them look like links?
2. Arrow(>) or forward slash(/)? ( To make it look like a trail the user followed or a standard file directory)
3. How not to make it the focal point ( more attraction should go to the main navigation menu)
4. Should i single out the current page - or leave it as such - since it is evident as it appears in the last position ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should there be underlines for the breadcrumbs to make them look like links?

They must respect overall site design. If all your navigation links are underlined (including your *main navigation menu*) then make them underlined. Just be **consistent**, exceptions must be justified.

> Arrow(>) or forward slash(/)? ( To make it look like a trail the user followed or a standard file directory)

I don't think it really matters because users are used to view both. However, if I have to decide then **I'd choose according to site content**. If it's hierarchical data then I'd use an arrow <kbd>></kbd> (or a similar glyph) to enforce this model. Krug's studies (citation from his *Don't make me think*) found that people have a stronger *sense of hierarchy* with <kbd>></kbd>.

If each page is just a *navigation path* but there isn't any strong hierarchical model then I'd go with <kbd>/</kbd>. Two examples:

```
Home > Documents > Reports > Marketing > Market Share > 2015
```

And:

```
Home / Administration / Users / Index
```

If you're in doubt I'd use <kbd>/</kbd> because users see the same *syntax* in URLs and it is (it should!) be easier to understand the concept of *path*. Note that this is just my opinion, above mentioned Krug asserts to always use <kbd>></kbd> in virtue of that *sense of hierarchy*.

> How not to make it the focal point ( more attraction should go to the main navigation menu)

With usual design tools: color and size. Exact combination depends on your site's design.

I'd use (if possible) all of them: smaller font to don't make it prominent and more subtle colors to move it to *background* but that's a decision that has to be done case-by-case.

> Should I single out the current page - or leave it as such - since it is evident as it appears in the last position?

Leave it there, breadcrumb control isn't just a shortcut for *browse back* feature (or an alternative navigation menu), it's a tool to exactly **tell you where you are**. Norman clearly stated <sup>[citation needed]</sup> to always include current page, even when you repeat exactly same information in the page title. Krug even suggests to make it bold.

Of course, current page should appear *different* and must not be clickable (unless you want to use it to refresh the current page but I'd avoid this in general and especially if dealing with forms).

Comment: Adriano, do you have that Norman reference? A quick search has some Nielsen articles showing up, but I'd like to read Norman's take on it.

Comment: @KenMohnkern I'm searching, I was sure it was on DoET but there I found just few paragraphs about this topic. I'll update when I got it!